# Is there hasta khechari mudrA?

Tags: yoga, mudra

It is known that khechari mudra is related to higher yogic practice.

But is there a hand mudra called khechari as well apart with the actual mudra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.

In The **Nitya ShodAshika Arnava Tantram** (NSA), Lord Shiva depicts how to form the Khechari Mudra using the hands.

The 3rd Patala of the text is entirely dedicated to describing the Mudras that are used during the worship of Goddess LalitA MahAtripura Sundari.

The 1st verse itself is this:

> Sri Devi UvAcha- BhagavanstripurAmudrAh suchitA na prakashitAh |
>   Katham virachanam tasAm kriyate vada shankara ||

Where Mother Goddess is saying - "O Bhagavan, you have , till now, only indicated about the Tripura Mudras but have not revealed them. Now, please describe how to form these MudrAs O Shankara."

Lord Shiva then gradually describes how to form some of the famous Mudras like - Trikhanda, SarvasamkshovakArini, TrailokyAkarshanakArini etc..etc...

Khechari- the Hasta MudrA, is then described in the following verses:

> Savyam dakshina deshe tu dakshinam savyadeshatah |
>  BAhum kritvA
>   maheshAni hastau samparivartya cha ||
>  KanishthAnAmike devi yuktA
>   tena kramena tu |
>  TarjanibyAm samAkryante sarvodhvamapi madhyame
>   ||
>  Angushthou tu maheshAni kArayet saralAvapi |
>  **Iyam sA
>   khechari nAma mudrA sarvottama priye** ||
>
> The left arm should be in the right direction and the right arm in the
>   left; then the  right arm should be placed encircling the left hand
>   and the fingers should be made to intertwined; Now, alternatively the
>   little fingers to be intertwined with the two ring fingers; the middle
>   fingers should be looking up and on their side the index fingers are
>   to be placed; and O Consort of Mahesha, by the help of the middle and
>   other fingers, the thumbs should be made to stand erect in a line. **O
>   beloved, in this manner is formed the best of all MudrAs called the
>   Khechari.**
>
> **NSA 3-15,16,17**

Further verses, given below, describe what's the significance of the Mudra is and what are few things that are achieved on it's mastery.

> Rachiteyam mahAdevi sarvatejopahArini |
>  BandhayivaitayA devi
>   drishyate sAdhakottamah ||
>  Yogini sarvavrindeistu jvalat pAvaka
>   sannibhah |
>  DAkini rAkini vrindair lAkinikAkini ganaih ||
>   SAkini hAkinibhistu dhyAteyam parameswari |
>  EtayA gyAtayA devi
>   yogininAm bhavet priyah ||
>  Yatah samayamudreyam sarvAsAm
>   parikirtitA ||
>
> O Great Goddess, one who forms this MudrA steals all others' Tejas, by
>   doing so. By forming this MudrA, the aspirant looks like a burning
>   flame of fire, along with all the Yoginis. O Supreme Goddess, the
>   Saktis- DAkini, RAkini, LAkini, KAkini, SAkini, HAkini- always
>   meditate upon this MudrA. This MudrA is also called the "Samaya MudrA" of
>   all the Saktis, and hence, the aspirant who has it's knowledge,
>   becomes very dear to the Yoginis.
>
> **NSA 3-18,19,20**

On these verses, one of the 3 commentators, Sri SivAnanda, interpret "Yogini" to mean -- BrAhmi... MahAlakshmi and other such Saktis.

And, another verse, which says, that by performing this Mudra one also achieves the power of flying (a Siddhi that the "original" Khechari is also supposed to bestow)

> Prajatoha prajato vAhapi shuchau deshehathavAha shuchau ||
>  Utthito
>   vopavishtastu chakramannishchalohapi vA |
>  Ucchisto vA shucirbhutvA
>   bhugyAno maithune ratah ||
>  MudrAyA madhyamAngulyou parivartya
>   kramena tu |
>  PArthive sthAnake yuktvA sadyah khecharatAm vrajeth
>   ||
>
> Whether the aspirant (who forms the MudrA) is pure or impure, whether
>   the place is pure or impure, whether he is on the move or static,
>   whether he has washed himself after eating or not etc--- in all such
>   circumstances, if he, upon performing the Khechari MudrA, places the
>   middle fingers on the place called "PArthiva" he immediately attains
>   Khecharatva (i.e gets the power of flying).
>
> **NSA 3-21,22,23.**

Sri BhAskara RAya's commentary on the "PArthiva SthAna" is as follows:

> PArthiva SthAna- "PArthiva sthAnam nAma
>   murdhAstitahmahAbindusthAnamityAhuh"   --- The place of the the
>   MahAbindu, that is situated in the palate (MurdhA) is called the "
>   PArthiva SthAna".

And for the word "KhecharatAm" he says:

> Khe bodha gagane charatiti khecharah | Khecharasya bhAvah khecharAta||
>
> OR
>
> Khe--- Bodha Gagane or the space or sky of consciousness; one who
>   travels in that is Khechara. And the BhAva (state) of Khechara is KhecharatA or the power of traveling in the space-consciousness..

So, as per him it's not literal but symbolic.

Comment: Is a pictorial representation available?

Comment: No not there in the book itself.. we have to form it by seeing the description given.. i think its difficult follow the instructions and form it.. anyways if i find a image for it i will upload it and will notify u that i have done so @rajesh

Answer (score 1):

Alright the explanation is directly from Shivji himself, but one who is learned can understand but this is only text that says Hasta the hand gesture of Kechari but the followers of the Shakti Sadhana call this as Sarva  Kechari mudra.

Sarva Kechari mudra or Hasta Kechari mudhra, for one to do, one must learn the yoni mudra, its done in hands only, if you have learnt Yogi mudra then you twist hands like in Garudasana then do the Yoni mudra it called Savra Kechari mudra.

This is 7th Mudra of Dasa Mudra Sampradaya worshipping Mother Lalitha.

Go to Youtube and search for Dasa Mudra you will get it easily, there are masters in this mudras.  Learning Yoni mudra takes only seconds but when twisted hand and thinking of doing Yoni for Kechari it looks practically impossible it seems from design of human body, but practice at it for 6 months you will get it.  Better pray to mother daily be a Sadhaka first then you will get it easily.

I used to do this very casually without knowing much, I am going to practice again may be in 10 days I will complete, probably then I can show you alive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).